# Integral of 1-forms and line integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, $\lambda: [a,b] \to X$, and $\omega :X \to (\mathbb R^n)^*$. The integral of the 1-form $\omega$ along $\lambda$ is defined as:
$$ \int_\lambda \omega = \lim_{|P|\to 0} \sum_{j=1}^k \omega(\lambda(\xi_j))(\lambda(t_j)-\lambda(t_{j-1})) $$
where, $P=\{t_0<t_1<\cdots < t_k\}$ is a tagged partition and $t_{j-1} \leq \xi_j \leq t_j$.

On the other hand, if $f:X \to \mathbb R$, then the line integral of $f$ along $\lambda$ is defined as:
$$ \int_\lambda f \, ds = \lim_{|P|\to 0} \sum_{j=1}^k f(\xi_j) \Vert \lambda(t_j)-\lambda(t_{j-1}) \Vert $$

Is the integral of 1-forms a generalization of line integrals? That is, given $f:X \to \mathbb R$, is there a 1-form $\omega :X \to (\mathbb R^n)^*$ such that
$$ \int_\lambda f \, ds = \int_\lambda \omega$$
holds?

Comment: Yes one form and the line integral will give the same result in actually computation. The only difference is on the conceptual level of what the ingral means. Actually one form is much bigger than another way to say a line integral. You can differentiate forms, and so some other kind of derivatives (interior derivative, lie derivative etc) , and wedge product but that sort of functionality doesn't make much sense in line integral.

Comment: I would suggest you check out Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry's last chapter. It explains the connection of forms with the regular vector calculus derivatives and such

Comment: @Buraian What do you mean by "give the same result in actually computation"? They act on different things, 1-forms and functions $f:X\to \mathbb R$ respectively.

Comment: Oh wait, I mistook the type of line integral you were talkign about. I meant, if you consider a vector line integral like the form $\int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{ds}$ then you'd see that the form formulation and the vector field formlation is equivalent

Comment: Have a look at [this play list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V96NogmVNXo&list=PL8erL0pXF3JYCn8Xukv0DqVIXtXJbOqdo&index=22). I am pretty sure it should clear your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot find a $1$-form on $X$ whose restriction to the parametrized curve $\lambda$ is $ds$ (which is notation and *not* a $1$-form itself) for $\lambda$. (For example, note that $\int_\lambda f\,ds$ does not depend on the orientation of $\lambda$, whereas the integral of any $1$-form does.)

However, if you *fix* a parametrized curve $\lambda$, you can in some situations find a $1$-form whose restriction to $\lambda$ will give $ds$ for that particular curve. For example, if $X=\Bbb R^2$ and you know the outward pointing *unit* normal $\vec n = (P,Q)$ to $\lambda$ at points $(x,y)\in\lambda$, then you can easily check that $ds = -Q\,dx + P\,dy$. (There are analogous formulas for integrating over hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^n$.) So, in this situation, you can compute the integral $\int_\gamma f\,ds$ by integrating the $1$-form $f(-Q\,dx + P\,dy)$. This generalizes to any surface with a Riemannian metric.

**REMARK**: As a remark way beyond the scope of this question, one of the most tantalizing features of *complex differential geometry* is the following. Given an $n$-dimensional complex (Kähler) manifold $X$, for every $k$ between $1$ and $n$ there is a differential ($2k$-) form that gives the induced volume element for any arbitrary $k$-dimensional complex submanifold of $X$.)